# CAShapeLayer not rendering as desired

Tags: swift, uikit, calayer, cashapelayer

I have a view that's got some `CAShapeLayer`s on it. I'm lazily instantiating it as follows:

```
lazy var myViewWithLayersOnIt: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 14,
                                                    y: 2),
                                    size: CGSize(width: 10,
                                                 height: 10)))
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let outerCircleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let outerPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: view.frame).cgPath
    outerCircleLayer.path = outerPath
    outerCircleLayer.position = view.center
    outerCircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(outerCircleLayer)

    let innerFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 1.5,
                                            y: 1.5),
                            size: CGSize(width: 8.5,
                                         height: 8.5))
    let innerCircleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let innerPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: innerFrame).cgPath
    innerCircleLayer.path = innerPath
    innerCircleLayer.position = view.center
    innerCircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(innerCircleLayer)

    return view
}()
```

While everything that's supposed to render on the screen is rendering, the `CAShapeLayer`s aren't going in the center of the `view`. I thought it might be due to lazily instantiating, so I ditched lazy and I see the exact same issue. What did I forget to do?

This is how it's rendering:

[image]

Thank you for reading. I welcome your input.

Comment: It is _never_ right to say things like `innerCircleLayer.position = view.center`, by the way. `view.center` is not the center of `view`. Rather, it is where `view` is _located_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `view.bounds` instead of `view.frame` for `outerPath`. No need to set the `position` of `outerCircleLayer`, nor `innerCircleLayer`.

```
lazy var myViewWithLayersOnIt: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 14,
                                                        y: 2),
                                        size: CGSize(width: 10,
                                                     height: 10)))
        

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    let outerCircleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let outerPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: view.bounds).cgPath /// bounds!
    outerCircleLayer.path = outerPath
//    outerCircleLayer.position = view.center
    outerCircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(outerCircleLayer)

    let innerFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 1.5,
                                                y: 1.5),
                                size: CGSize(width: 8.5,
                                             height: 8.5))
    let innerCircleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let innerPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: innerFrame).cgPath
    innerCircleLayer.path = innerPath
//    innerCircleLayer.position = view.center
    innerCircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(innerCircleLayer)

    return view
}()
```

Result:

[image: circles centered inside each other]

The red circle is off center because

```
let innerFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 1.5,
                                        y: 1.5),
                        size: CGSize(width: 8.5,
                                     height: 8.5))
```

should be

```
let innerFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.75,
                                        y: 0.75),
                        size: CGSize(width: 8.5,
                                     height: 8.5))
```

8.5 + 0.75 + 0.75 = 10, not 8.5 + 1.5 + 1.5 = 11.5

[image: red circle's center fixed]

Comment: Thank you! I've been so buried in networking code and RxSwift lately I forgot UIKit stuff. LOL.